# How to change between pages with Selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I am trying to create a Test Case with Selenium, where I will create an application in one Page named "Policy". In this Application I want to create some Members. To go from Policy page to Members Page you have to press the button "Members" after you've successfully created the Policy Application. After creating all the members you need you have to navigate back to Policy page to continue.
(Main Menu Page -> Policy Page -> Members Page -> Policy Page)

I am using Page Object Pattern. I successfully log in the App, navigate to Policy Page, create the Application, but cannot go to Members Page in order to continue my Test. And of course, get back to Policy page. How can I do that? My test fails after message "Policy Created succesfully" is shown in Eclipse Console.

My code is:

```
@Test
public void TEST1_NavigateToPolicy() throws Exception {
    MenuPage.policySelection();
    }


@Test
public void TEST2_PolicyCreation() throws Exception {

    PolicyPage.handleMultipleWindows("Policy"); 
    PolicyPage.createPolicy( some requirements here);
    PolicyPage.checkMessageByIdContains("Operation Apply executed Successfully", MESSAGE);
            System.out.println("Policy Created succesfully");
            }


 @Test
 public void TEST3_MemberCreation() {

    //Navigate to Member Page and Create Member
    PolicyPage.clickButton(MEMBERS_BUTTON);
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify whether 1) you need to know how to switch between windows in UI and create members or 2) you need to know how to transfer control to page object of a new page.

Comment: I need to know how to transfer control to the new "Members" Page and then transfer back to "Policy".
I guess to switch between windows I can use:
MembersPage.handleMultipleWindows("Members");
correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Then this will be my sample code for you.

```
@Test       
 public void TEST3_MemberCreation() {     
homePage = login(admin);     
PolicyPage policyPage = homePage.NavigateToPolicyPage();     
policyPage.handleMultipleWindows("Policy");      
    policyPage.createPolicy( some requirements here);     
    policyPage.checkMessageByIdContains("Operation Apply executed Successfully", MESSAGE);     
            System.out.println("Policy Created succesfully");     
            }     
MembersPage membersPage = policyPage.clickMembersButton;(You have to handle the page navigation code inside this method and return MembersPage object)
membersPage.createMember(Data);     

}     

MembersPage clickMembersButton(){     
element.click();     
switchTo.window(newWindowHandle);     
return new MembersPage();     
}
```

Comment: What is newWindowHandle supposed to be? Could you please format your code properly?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm testing the actual navigation via the UI I like to do as much navigating as possible by browsing directly to the page I need. It gives the test fewer opportunities to fail, and is often quicker as it can save extra steps.

So, I'd browse directly to the page simply using:

```
driver.get("yourURL");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually want to test the overall process as well (record time needed for each task, etc), so navigating through the UI is important.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation between Policy and Members page can be done by:

```
@Test
public void TEST3_MemberCreation() {

 // Create a policy
 TEST2_PolicyCreation();

 // Store the current window handle
 String policyPageWindow = _webDriver.getWindowHandle();

 // Clicking the "Members" button on Policy page
 WebElement clickMemBerPageButton = _webDriver.findElement(By.name("MEMBERS_BUTTON"));
 clickMemBerPageButton.click();

 // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened "Members" window)
 for (String winHandle : _webDriver.getWindowHandles()) {
    _webDriver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 
 }

 //code to do something on new window (Members page)

 // Switch back to policy page
 _webDriver.switchTo().window(policyPageWindow);
 }
```